# How can I find a good idea for a dragon-battle scene?

Tags: scene, ideas, combat

First of all, hello!
I really, really, really *do* want to have an answer for my question. I’ve been writing a novel about dragons, but I can’t finish it. I’m just at loss of words (and ideas).

To summarize the plot, it’s about a young adult, **Luther**, who obtains a female dragon that he’s going to name **Chance** as a pet. He’ll receive an invitation from a big community named the League which will ask him to join it because its members truly need new and young dragon Riders. He’s forced to, and in this League, he discovers the existence of other dragons and a lot of people having different ranks. It goes from Apprentice to Master, passing by Rider, Healer, Whisperer, and eventually Trainer. There’s a lot to explain about that, so I’ll avoid it because it isn’t the major problem.

At the end of the story, the “big bad villain” shows up, being a huge, enormous, giant dragon named Nameless (yes, I used adjectives that meant the same thing three times, and yes, his name is Nameless), commanded by a human called Preston. It’s him who’s the big problem because Nameless obeys him, and if he dies, then the dragon won’t have any order to listen to and will stop causing trouble to everyone; that’s the League’s idea. However, it’s a bit more complicated to kill Preston since he’s on the dragon’s back.

What you don’t know for now is that Luther had a pretty big quarrel between some of the League’s Masters, which led him to get suspended of his duty as a Rider. His equipment for riding Chance were taken away from him and his dragon was imprisoned to prevent him from riding her. Luther gets into a so-called depression because he thinks everything is falling apart, but that’s when one of his friends shows up and they have a discussion and, well, a lot of things happen, until finally, Luther starts to boil with courage (and rage) and decides to help the League defeat the enemy.

So, back to Preston and Nameless... Everyone is surprised when they see Luther flying towards them on Chance’s back, his equipment on him, and well, he becomes the hero of the day when he fights Nameless. At the end, he and his dragon die beside each other.

That’s where I’m stuck. I thought about many ideas, each one not fitting my ideal, until finally, I watched the movie **How To Train Your Dragon**. Right, I know it’s completely out of context for you, but actually, this movie is my inspiration. The battle at the final scene is incredible... Someone could watch it for me, please? It’s great. I mean, look at the script. To resume it: Hiccup saves Astrid with Toothless, enrages the Green Death, the three go flying up to the dark clouds high above, Toothless manages to enrage his opponent more, he and Hiccup fall down, the Night Fury spits out his strange blue-and-purple fireball into the Green Death’s mouth, its body ignites and explodes from the inside, Hiccup gets thrown off Toothless’s back when the Green Death’s tail hits them, and Toothless saves him from the fire.

Aye aye. That’s all. What I had to say (to stop make you wait for my problem) is that I can’t figure out how to imagine a scene worthy of this one. I don’t mean to recreate something like this, but I just want to take the reader away, make him see the fire and the tension inside everyone’s eyes. I want them to be afraid for my characters. However, I just can’t find an epic scene in my head. I can only see my characters instead of HTTYD’s because they fit. Please, someone has an idea for an epic scene? I’m not asking to give me every detail you can imagine, just some beautiful moments showing friendship (Even though you don’t have a clear view on Luther’s and Chance’s friendship, like if Luther steals her food, is she going to kill him or give him a last chance?) or a fighting spirit or anything else that could be an inspiration for the battle.

I hope I explained myself clearly. If not, please, ask me anything you’d want to know.

Comment: There is way too much unnecessary exposition in this question. We don't need to know the entire plot to understand the question. Really it's only the last paragraph or two that actually matter, but right now we have to wade through all the plot summary to get to it. Try to be concise and think about what we REALLY need to know to answer your question, and make sure the question itself is very clearly spelled out and not buried in other commentary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write whatever is on your mind. A random idea, a picture, a phrase, a piece of dialogue, and object, whatever.

I personally am writing a fantasy series, and when I get stuck, I write whatever I think about.

For example, I’m my first book, the queens curse, my main character and two of her friends are captured by fairies. They all feel very stupid, because, well, they’re fairies. The leader of the fairies pulls out a silver torch, and the main character realizes they were going to be burned alive.

Then I got stuck.

So I thought about how the fairies were all “evil” and wearing black. Then I thought about the elves in my story, how some were willing to help humans, others bent on killing them. Then I thought, shouldn’t it be the same for all creatures?

So I thought about how there should be good fairies too. And then there ended up being this awesome fight scene between good fairies and bad fairies, which to my surprise didn’t sound dumb but actually very cool.

The point of the story is this:

When in doubt, write about the first thing that comes to mind, and you just might end up with an amazing scene.